# C# object serialization safely and best methods? Anyone can give me ans?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Object serialization method ? I am creating my own arraylist serialization application.

Comment: There's no way anyone but you can answer that question. There are many ways to serialize objects, such as binary serialization, xml, json, protobuf, etc. They have their pros and their cons but you mention no criteria at all. The best approach would be to check them out and then decide.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is a huge topic. Without discussing lots of details about what your requirements are, only vague guidance is possible, in which case: by default, probably keep it simple and use generic things like JSON or XML; Json.NET has [over 100 samples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm) which are very reasonable for general-purpose scenarios. If you have specific requirements about size/performance/compatibility/capabilities/etc, then other tools or formats may be more appropriate. The only main rules are:

1. [do not blindly use `BinaryFormatter`](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html) (or `NetDataContractSerializer`)
2. don't roll your own home-baked serialization format/code unless you know a *lot* about serialization and can explain why none of the *myriad* of pre-existing libraries won't work for your specific scenario